# Why is pip not working properly on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Iv'e Looked and Looked and cannot figure out this problem. Pip will not work for anything at all and it is causing me much trouble. pip3 will work, but pip will not work at all. keeps spitting out this error having to do with cryptography module. other posts said to pip remove enum and pip install enum34, but the problem is that pip won't even allow me to do this. When I try to do anything with pip, it's spits out this error or similar.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2693, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/general_name.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Thank You Very Much

Comment: how did you install pip? Can you `sudo easy_install pip` again? Also, have you seen this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206121/pip-install-gives-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable/206136

Comment: Still spits out error

Comment: to verify, you mean you tried the solutions in the thread I linked above and *none* worked? Meaning you updated your `python-distlib` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bash
curl 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Doesn't Workk, spits out roughly the same error in the same place

Comment: Doens't Work. Also spits out similar error when i try to run a python script

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the enum or cryptography module, but currently, enum is uninstalled and enum34 is installed like the other people said to do, but it still doesn't work at all

Comment: Ok, here is what you are going to do. uninstall enum
`pip uninstall enum`
then install enum34
`pip install -U enum34`

Comment: -U parameter is for the latest version

Comment: Like i said, pip won't work at all, so i can't do pip uninstall enum